# SOLR Cloud - routing changes from 'compositeId' to 'implicit'

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a simple SOLR cloud setup with 2 nodes and 4 shards.

When I create the collection everything works as expected and each shard gets a proper range for the compositeId router to work correctly.

However, without any actions on my part, at least I'm not aware of any, my SOLR Cloud routing changes to implicit and the number of shards is also incorrect 2 instead of 4.

Looking through the Collection API I see that I'm able to choose routing during the collection creation process, but I have no idea why my routing gets changed afterwards at random times when data starts flowing.

Maybe it has something to do with the way we start our SOLR instances? Obviously this doesn't happen all the time so it's hard to pinpoint the scenario.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the embedded zookeeper or an external ensemble? Could it be that you're actually losing your cluster state completely?

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same issue.

To make this work properly with compositeId,

1. Stop Zookeeper and Solr.
2. Delete version-2 folder of zookeeper.
3. Edit core.properties of newly created shard (collectionName_shard1_0_replica1) and make the following changes,

   a. name=collectionName_shard1_0_replica1 must be changed to name=collectionName_shard1_replica1
   b. shard=shard1_0 must be changed to shard=shard1
   c. similarly change the directory name
4. Similarly edit core.properties of newly created shard2 (collectionName_shard1_1_replica1) and make the following changes,

   a. name=collectionName_shard1_1_replica1 must be changed to name=collectionName_shard2_replica1
   b. shard=shard1_1 must be changed to shard=shard2
   c. similarly change the directory name
5. Start zookeeper and Solr.
6. Commit the splitted collection.

Hope this will work